# How to connect a form into another phtml view in Zend 2 framework

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am new at Zend2:

I have a form, and in the first stage I create a new ViewModel and return it:

```
return new ViewModel(array('form' => $form, 'messages' => $messages));
```

In the post stage when the data comes back from the browser, how can I connect this same form to a new View (which has the same elements maybe less, maybe more) or create another form and rassign it the old form's data and relate it to a new view to show?

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I tried to do the following:

$form->setAttribute('action', $this->url('auth/index/login-post.phtml'));

But still shows the old one.

When I do this:

return $this->redirect()->toRoute('auth/default', array('controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'login-post'));

I get error page: The requested controller was unable to dispatch the request.

When I get the post of the request I need to load another view, I mean how do I specify which view is connected to which form?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? [The Documentation](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#zend-form) covers `Zend\Form` quite ok. If you're talking about a "multi-step-form" you need to save the previous forms data inside the session.

Comment: @Sam when I get the post of the request I need to load another view, i mean how do i specify which view is coneected with wich FORM?

Comment: I'm still a bit unsure about what you want to do. Usually when you post a Form and the Form is INVALID, you are redirected to the form including error messages. If the Form is valid the data is inserted into the database and then you're being redirected to another page. What EXACTLY are you trying to do, don't say "load another view", tell me the concept of your approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The forms do not themselves have any knowledge of the view. If you wish to change the view after completing the form submission; where this new view provides perhaps a different form, this is something that should be done within the controller.

A (non-working) example with a few options on how a different view could be returned.

```
class FooController extends AbstractActionController
{

    public function getFooForm()
    {
        return $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Form\Foo');
    }

    public function getBarForm()
    {
        return $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Form\Bar')
    }


    public function fooAction()
    {
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $form    = $this->getFooForm();

        if ($request->isPost()) {
            $form->setData($request->getPost());

            // Is the posted form vaild
            if ($form->isValid()) {

                // Forms validated data
                $data = $form->getData(); 

                // Now there are a few options

                // 1. Return a new view with the data
                $view = new ViewModel($data);
                $view->setTemplate('path/to/file');

                return $view;

                // OR Option 2 - Redirect

                return $this->redirect()->toRoute('bar', $someRouteParams);


                // Option 3 - Dispatch a new controller action
                // and then return it's view model/response

                // We can also pass on the posted data so the controller
                // action that is dispathed will already have our POSTed data in the
                // request
                $request->setPost(new \Zend\Stdlib\Parameters($data));

                return $this->forward()->dispatch('App\Controller\Foo', array('action' => 'bar'));

            }
        }
        // Render default foo.phtml or use $view->setTemplate('path/to/view')
        // and render the form, which will post back to itself (fooAction)
        return new ViewModel(array('form' => $form));
    }


    public function barAction()
    {
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $form    = $this->getBarForm();

        if ($request->isPost()) {
            $form->setData($request->getPost());
            // ....      
        }

        // Renders the bar.phtml view
        return $this->viewModel(array('form' => $form));
    }

}
```

From what I understand form your question, you would need to be using *option 3* as the new view should populate a second form with it's already validated data.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to something like an edit view then you just need to bind your object to the form.

```
$form->bind($yourObject);
```

http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.form.quick-start.html#binding-an-object

Otherwise you can make the form post to any controller action using by setting it:

```
$form->setAttribute('action', $this->url('contact/process'));
```

Maybe post what code you have and more specifics and I'm sure you will get some more detailed answers

Comment: now $yourObject is a normal array holding new data to assign to my form right? And what about contact/process? it's my view? like view/contact/process.phtml ?

Comment: I tried to do the following: $form->setAttribute('action', $this->url('auth/index/login-post.phtml')); where the original return is : return new ViewModel(array('form' => $form, 'messages' => $messages));doesnt work it shows the old page.